# Kivy app crash on Android with jnius error

Tags: python, java, android, kivy, pyjnius

I wrote a small application using Python Kivy on a PC, it works fine, but on Android it crashes with this error:

```
05-02 12:54:26.906 9978 10018 F org.test.myapp: runtime.cc:655\] native: #10 pc 000401c1 /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/\_python_bundle/site-packages/ jnius/jnius.so (???)

 

05-02 12:54:27.016 10086 10086 F DEBUG : #07 pc 000401c1 /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/\_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so

 

05-02 12:54:27.788 868 903 D DropBoxManagerService: #07 pc 000401c1 /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/\_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so

 

05-02 12:54:27.924 868 10091 D DropBoxManagerService: #07 pc 000401c1 /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/\_python_bundle/site-packages/jnius/jnius.so
```

I am using:

- Python version: 3.9.9
- Kivy: (2.0.0)
- Kivy-Garden: (0.1.5)
- buildozer: (1.5.1.dev0)
- Cython: (0.29.34)
- OS: XUbuntu 18.04

The buildozer.spec file looks like this:

```
\# (list) Application requirements

 

\# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy

 

requirements = python3,kivy,pyjnius==1.4.2,beautifulsoup4,pyrogram,tgcrypto,pyQiwiP2P,requests,urllib3,chardet,certifi,idna,lxml,aiohttp,multidict,attr,yarl,async_timeout,attrs,Pillow,cchardet,charset -normalizer==2.1.1,aiosignal,frozenlist,android,libtool,pathlib,pathlib2,pysocks,pyaes,httpx,sniffio,httpcore,soupsieve,h11,loguru,phonenumbers,email_validator,response_report,SimpleQIWI

\# (list) Permissions

 

\# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)

 

android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

\# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi

 

android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/\*.so

 

android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/\*.so

 

android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/\*.so

 

android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/\*.so

 

android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/\*.so
```

Also, I added these lines to the main.py file, but it didn't help:

```
import jnius

dropbox = jnius.autoclass("android.os.DropBoxManager")
```